# App is crashing, don't know why?

Tags: android, button, crash

I have an app that runs ok on emulator, I tried to install it on my phone and it is working great, but on android market i got 8 crash reports. People are complaining that app is crashing on a button click that I upgraded in latest version. On my phone everything is working great. How can I find where the problem is ??

NullPointerException
in bonbon2$1.onClick()

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at cro.perger.bonbon.bonbon2$1.onClick(bonbon2.java:64)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2501)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9111)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

java.lang.NullPointerException
at cro.perger.bonbon.bonbon2$1.onClick(bonbon2.java:56)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

java.lang.NullPointerException
at cro.perger.bonbon.bonbon2$1.onClick(bonbon2.java:48)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT:

This is code of file bonbon2.java that is causing problems

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class bonbon2 extends Activity 
{

    Button btnKombinacija;
    EditText text1;
    Context context=this;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);


        btnKombinacija = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btnKombinacija.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {   
                CheckBox maliRazgovori = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
                CheckBox maliSMS = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
                CheckBox maliInternet = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox8);
                CheckBox srednjiRazgovori = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
                CheckBox srednjiSMS = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);
                CheckBox srednjiInternet = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox9);
                CheckBox velikiRazgovori = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                CheckBox velikiSMS = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
                CheckBox velikiInternet = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);
                text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                *if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == true && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {*

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (20 minuta prema svim mrežama) i cijena joj je 10kn.";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                *} else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == true && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {*

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (60 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama) i cijena joj je 10kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                *} else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == true 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {*

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (50 MB prometa) i cijena joj je 10kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == true && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (80 minuta prema svim mrežama) i cijena joj je 30kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == true && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (200 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama) i cijena joj je 30kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == true 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (300 MB prometa) i cijena joj je 30kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == true && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (200 minuta izvan mreže, 300 minuta u mreži) i cijena joj je 60kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == true && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (500 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama) i cijena joj je 60kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == true) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (1 GB prometa) i cijena joj je 60kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                }else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == true && maliSMS.isChecked() == true && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (20 minuta prema svim mrežama, 60 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama) i cijena joj je 20kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                }  else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == true && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == true && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (20 minuta prema svim mrežama, 200 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama) i cijena joj je 40kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == true && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == true && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (20 minuta prema svim mrežama, 500 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama) i cijena joj je 70kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == true && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == true 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (20 minuta prema svim mrežama, 50 MB prometa) i cijena joj je 20kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == true && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == true 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (20 minuta prema svim mrežama, 300 MB prometa) i cijena joj je 40kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == true && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == true) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (20 minuta prema svim mrežama, 1 GB prometa) i cijena joj je 70kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == true && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == true && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (80 minuta prema svim mrežama, 60 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama) i cijena joj je 40kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == true && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == true && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (80 minuta prema svim mrežama, 200 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama) i cijena joj je 60kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == true && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == true && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (80 minuta prema svim mrežama, 500 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama) i cijena joj je 90kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == true 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == true && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (80 minuta prema svim mrežama, 50 MB prometa) i cijena joj je 40kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == true && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == true 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (80 minuta prema svim mrežama, 300 MB prometa) i cijena joj je 60kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == true && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == true) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (80 minuta prema svim mrežama, 1 GB prometa) i cijena joj je 90kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == true && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == true && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (200 minuta izvan mreže, 300 minuta u mreži, 60 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama) i cijena joj je 70kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == true && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == true && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (200 minuta izvan mreže, 300 minuta u mreži, 200 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama) i cijena joj je 90kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == true && velikiSMS.isChecked() == true && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (200 minuta izvan mreže, 300 minuta u mreži, 500 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama) i cijena joj je 120kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == true 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == true && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (200 minuta izvan mreže, 300 minuta u mreži, 50 MB prometa) i cijena joj je 70kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == true 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == true && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (200 minuta izvan mreže, 300 minuta u mreži, 300 MB prometa) i cijena joj je 90kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == true && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == true) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (200 minuta izvan mreže, 300 minuta u mreži, 1 GB prometa) i cijena joj je 120kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == true && maliInternet.isChecked() == true 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (60 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama, 50 MB prometa) i cijena joj je 20kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == true && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == true 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == false) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (60 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama, 300 MB prometa) i cijena joj je 40kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == true && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == false && velikiInternet.isChecked() == true) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (60 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama, 1 GB prometa) i cijena joj je 70kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                } else if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() == false && maliSMS.isChecked() == false && maliInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() == true && srednjiSMS.isChecked() == false && srednjiInternet.isChecked() == false 
                        && velikiRazgovori.isChecked() == false && velikiSMS.isChecked() == true && velikiInternet.isChecked() == true) {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži (80 minuta prema svim mrežama, 500 SMS-ova prema svim mrežama, 1 GB prometa) i cijena joj je 150kn";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                }else {

                            String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija nije dobra, molim odaberi ponovo!";
                            text1.setText(String
                                    .valueOf(kombinacija));

                }


                }
        });
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.about:    
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Paketi - info");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("Kao i inače u bonbonu, ni u jednoj od ovih kombinacija ne plaćaš naknadu za uspostavu poziva :-) " +
                        "Obračunska jedinica za pozive je 1 sekunda, a obračunska jedinica za prijenos podataka je 100 kB.  " +
                        "Paket će ti se aktivirati u najkraćem mogućem roku, a najkasnije u roku od 24 sata. O aktivaciji paketa " +
                        "primit ćeš SMS obavijest, zato pričekaj poruku prije nego što ga počneš koristiti. Možeš kupiti samo jednu " +
                        "veličinu paketa razgovora, SMS-a ili interneta npr. mali paket razgovora, srednji paket SMS-a i veliki paket " +
                        "interneta. No ne moraš kupiti sva tri paketa odjednom – nekad možeš kupiti jedan, dva ili čak nijedan, ovisi " +
                        "koja ti kombinacija u tom trenutku treba. Ne pristaj na kompromise nego si složi onu kombinaciju koja te u tom " +
                        "trenutku pali! Paket koji odabereš vrijedi 30 dana od dana aktivacije i nakon isteka će ti se automatski reaktivirati " +
                        "ako imaš dovoljno novca na računu, ako ti nije istekla valjanost bonbon računa i ako paket nisi u međuvremenu sam " +
                        "deaktivirao. O isteku paketa i mogućnosti da ga deaktiviraš bit ćeš obaviješten SMS porukom prije isteka." +
                        "Nakon isteka 30 dana možeš složiti svoju novu bonbon kombinaciju. Ili zadržati staru, ako ti tako odgovara :-)" +
                        "Ako potrošiš svoj paket unutar 30 dana (o čemu ćemo te obavijestiti SMS-om), sam možeš kupiti novi paket ali jednake v" +
                        "eličine. Ako želiš unutar tih 30 dana aktivirati paket druge veličine, kontaktiraj nas :-) Ako ne želiš kupovati novi " +
                        "paket – ne moraš, tada jednostavno nastavi razgovarati, slati poruke i surfati po standardno dobrim bonbon cijenama iz " +
                        "osnovne tarife. Ako svoj paket ne potrošiš unutar 30 dana, nepotrošene minute, SMS-ove i MB-e više nećeš moći koristiti." +
                        "Ako si aktivirao mali, srednji ili veliki paket razgovora, trebaš imati barem 1 lipu na računu da bi mogao koristiti minute " +
                        "uključene u paket. I na kraju, ovo ćeš se sigurno pitati pa ti odmah dajemo odgovor: ako sudjeluješ u promociji „pričaj for " +
                        "free do 2020.“ i imaš aktiviran neki od paketa razgovora, prvo će ti se trošiti minute iz promocije, a tek nakon toga minute " +
                        "iz paketa. ");
                sb.append("\n");
                alertDialog.setMessage(sb.toString());
                alertDialog.setButton("Povratak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   }  
                });

                alertDialog.show();

                                break;
            case R.id.exit: 

                    finish();
                }
        return true;


        }
}
```

The lines 48, 56 and 64 that are in error report are ITALIC.... So i don't know what is problem here :(

Comment: Without seeing any code, we can't help you.

Comment: I think you have some problem in your XML layout or in the programmed layout, if you use it. Can you give us an XML code of your button?

Comment: I will update my question tomorow with code, because I don't have it with me.... But is there any way to see in wich file is error, from thoose reports up ??

Comment: Yes, there is the filename and the line in the exception, usually it's the root (first line). E.g. the first `NullPointerException` occured in bonbon2.java at line 64 (*at cro.perger.bonbon.bonbon2$1.onClick(**bonbon2.java:64**)*).

Comment: So i should check the file bonbon2.java at line64...Ok tomorow I will paste code from bonbon2.java filehere.

Comment: Ok I edited question with code. Can you help me now, please....,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is extremely difficult to read... just as a programming tip, you should refactor it so instead of else ifs for 6 variables, you have cascaded conditionals.

Another quick tip: instead of `if(box.isChecked == false)`, just use `if(!box.isChecked)`. Same effect, much more readable code.

That said, it looks like your activity is not able to find the layout resources for the checkboxes you've provided.

Android recycles views fairly aggressively, I would guess that the system is recycling these views when they're not on the screen, and that's causing a null pointer exception when you try to reference it with `box.isChecked`.

Make sure your `velikiRazgovori`,  `velikiSMS`, and `velikiInternet` boxes (as these are the three on the lines that are throwing the error) are all displayed on the screen.

You can debug this by placing each of the three conditionals on seperate lines like so:

```
if (maliRazgovori.isChecked() && 
   !maliSMS.isChecked() && 
   !maliInternet.isChecked() && 
   !srednjiRazgovori.isChecked() && 
   !srednjiSMS.isChecked() && 
   !srednjiInternet.isChecked() && 
   !velikiRazgovori.isChecked() && 
   !velikiSMS.isChecked() && 
   !velikiInternet.isChecked()
{
   String kombinacija = "Odabrana kombinacija sadrži 
        (20 minuta prema svim mrežama) i cijena joj je 10kn.";
   text1.setText(kombinacija);
}
```

Give this a try with the conditions I stated above and see what happens.

Good luck!

Comment: I found where the error is :( It was in the layout, but not the default layout, but in the layouts for the small and xlarge screens. Because of this app was working fine on my phone, but no so good on other phones .....

Comment: Great! :) Make sure you mark answers as correct if they helped you find the solution to your problem, it will make people more willing to help you out in the future when they see that you accept questions often!